# Positive look behind discrepancy in web app

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a web app that allows a user to specify rules to extract values from a string of text.  The rules are entered through a HTML form and saves to a DB.

Regex: **(?<=(\bRATE: \b))[A-Z]{3}**

I've tested an expression using http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ *(great tool!)*

However there is a difference when it is evaluated in my application.

What the regex should do given the string "**RATE: USD75.00**" is to extract the 3 letter currency code "**USD**".

However.....
In my web app it returns "**RAT**"

It appears to be ignoring the "**<**" part of the positive look behind.

Do I need to escape this character?

Has anyone experience a similar problem?

Comment: Are you sure of your code? I've tried your RE on http://www.cookcomputing.com/regex (which uses Silverlight, so .Net) and it works. Try posting your code.

Comment: This works as expected on [ideone](http://ideone.com/13RvN3). Are you sure that you are not altering the text somehow? Maybe the regex value gets HTML encoded?

Comment: Encoding does seem like a likely culprit Alex.  I'll have a look through the code and see if I can nail it down.  Thanks for the link Teejay

Answer (score 1):

Why using additional parentheses in the lookbehind expression?

They are not necessary and could be a possible reason for wrong result as the parentheses define a capturing group although nothing can be captured from a string in a lookbehind expression. It could be that the used regular expression engine fails on this scenario with capturing parentheses within a lookbehind expression.

Also the second `\b` is useless as the positive lookbehind checks for the string "**RATE:** " and therefore the 3 letters of currency code must be always after a space character which of course is a word boundary.

Therefore I suggest (very late now) to use `(?<=\bRATE: )[A-Z]{3}` and I suppose that the used regular expression engine returns the 3 letters of currency code as expected.